# How can I create JSON file into my Mac, while I submit FORM?

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vuelidate

i got easy form. I need to save data from submitted form to JSON file into my mac.

What can I use for it? AXIOS? VUELIDATE? I have to create frontend - create form, save file, send it to server (with colleague servisa) valid data, popup window with "DONE"

thank you

```
<div>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label
          for="order-id">
        </label>

        <input
          required
          minlength="1"
          id="order-id"
          type="text"
          placeholder="1547089" />
      </div>

    <div> 
        <label
          for="password">
        </label>
        <input
          v-model="password"
          required
          minlength="4"
          maxlength="4"
          type="password"
          placeholder="****" />
    </div>
        <div
          id="div-submit">
            <button
              v-bind:disabled="password.length < 4"
              id="submit"
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      password: '',
    }
  },
  setup(){
    const result = ref(null)

    fetch("http://localhost:5173/?")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>result.value = data);

    return { result }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% I get what you are looking for: You want to download a JSON file to your computer?

For security reasons you can't do this directly, but there is a workaround I used. You need an `<a>` in your template and a function that updates it and clicks it with code.

JS/TS:

```
const downloadAnchorElem: Ref<HTMLAnchorElement | null> = ref(null);
const downloadAttrDownload = ref('');
const downloadAttrHref = ref('');
async function download(data: any) {
    const dataStr = 'data:text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
    downloadAttrHref.value = dataStr;
    downloadAttrDownload.value = data.title + '.json';
    await nextTick()
    downloadAnchorElem.value!.click();
}
```

Template:

```
<a ref="downloadAnchorElem" style="display: none;"
    :href="downloadAttrHref"
    :download="downloadAttrDownload"></a>
```

Then you can just call `download()` with a JavaScript object to trigger a download prompt in your browser. If you already have a JSON string you can modify the method and pass the string in, then you no longer need the `JSON.stringify` part, but you still need the `encodeURIComponent`.